# how to use jquery image gallery inside a lightbox/modal?

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask some help with a jquery light box/image gallery I’m having.

The site I’m working on talks about real estate, on mouseover an overlay appears offering a “more info” tour. when clicked a light box is supposed to appear containing more information about the property.

The light box is also supposed to contain a slideshow of additional images.

The mouseover overlay and light box work fine, but I can’t get the image slider to work within the light box.
I see all the contents of the slider, sample images that should be hidden are not, and all the functionality is missing.

These are the two plugins I’m using:

https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-modal

http://i-like-robots.github.com/jQuery-Slideshow/

I'm using jquery 1.8.3 as my base and both plugins work with that base.

Here is a fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/stephanief0042/cwKKY/6/

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Image gallery in lightbox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modal.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="outerspaces.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rs.modal.js"></script>
<script src="outerspaces.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hover firstdiv">Hover here
<div class="overlay-test">overlay test</div>
<!-- First overlay-->
<div class="overlay" style="visibility:hidden">
<a href="#host-space" class="modal-toggle-1"><img src="images/request-a-tour-overlay.png" /></a>
</div>​
<div class="host-space-content" style="display: none;">
<div id="host-space" class="host-space">
<div id="host-image-gallery">
<div class="hostname">Host Name</div>
<div class="hostaddress">Host Address</div>
<!-- Image gallery space -->
<div class="slideshow" data-transition="crossfade" data-loop="true" data-skip="false">
<ul class="carousel">
<li class="slide"><img src="http://placebox.es/440/200/d97ef2/f5f5f5" alt="" width="440"                   height="200" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="http://placebox.es/440/200/50ac3d/f5f5f5" alt="" width="440" height="200" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="http://placebox.es/440/200/0a77bb/f5f5f5" alt="" width="440" height="200" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- END image gallery space -->
<div>Host short description</div>
<div>Host indstry/vibe info</div>
<div>Host Website link</div>
<!-- END host-space --></div>
<div id="host-info-area">
<div>Host Info area</div>
<!-- END host-space --></div>
<!-- END host-space-content --></div>
<!-- END CONTAINING DIV --></div>
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
// Create slideshow instances
var $s = $('.slideshow').slides(),
// Access an instance API
api = $s.eq(0).data('slides');
// Transition select
$('select[name=transition]').on('change', function()
{
api.redraw( this.value );
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.modal-toggle-1').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.modal.open($('#host-space').clone(), {
maxHeight: 600,maxWidth: 874,fitViewport: true
});
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My jquery skills are not strong and other than a couple small styling changes I’m using the default examples.

Any help would be appreciated, if I need to provide more detail to my question please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Have any code or fiddle as sample?

Comment: I'va added my code, if you need a fiddle to help me, please let me know and I'll create one. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Having a fiddle might help..

Comment: added a fiddle, thanks again for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. Try this and let me know how it goes. Just moved the slider code inside the function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/qZWDZ/

```
$('.modal-toggle-1').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $.modal.open($('#host-space').clone(), {
      maxHeight: 600,maxWidth: 874,fitViewport: true
   });

    // Create slideshow instances
    var $s = $('.slideshow').slides(),

    // Access an instance API
    api = $s.eq(0).data('slides');

    // Transition select
    $('select[name=transition]').on('change', function()
    {
       api.redraw( this.value );
    });
});
```

Comment: THANKS! I'll be trying it today, and I'll let you know how it goes :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to take so long, I haven't forgotten you - the site that this is going into had been giving me different issues I had to resolve first. I'll be trying again tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a different solution (the site requirements changed), but this did work for the question I asked, Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you arent fully experience with jscript, I would recommend using a lightbox plugin that allows already support galleries such as prettyphoto http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

The sample code has an example which look as follows:

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="You can add caption to pictures."><img src="images/thumbnails/t_1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a>

<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a>

<a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_3.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fire!" /></a>

<a href="images/fullscreen/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_4.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Rock climbing" /></a>
```

What makes this all work is the rel attribute. rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" is what makes it work, the text inside the brackets [pp_gal] is what groups the images into a group/album.

Comment: I did look around for a suitable contributed plugin, but didn't find anything that meets the need. As a last resort I"ll be suggesting this, but first I'd like to try finding an answer to my question - thanks for replying!